# Prove the measurability of a set related to sequence of bounded functions

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be measurable space, $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb N} $ a sequence of measurable functions $f_n: X \longmapsto \mathbb C$.

I would like to show that the set $\{x\in X: f_1(x),f_2(x), \cdots \quad \text{is a bounded sequence} \}$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal A$.

Let $A= \{x\in X: f_1(x),f_2(x), \cdots \quad \text{is a bounded sequence} \}$

and let the measurable functions
\begin{align*}
\varphi_n: X \to \mathbb C, \\
 x \longmapsto \vert f_n(x) \rvert.
\end{align*}

I hesitate to choose between this two methods:

1. $$
   x\in A \iff \forall n \mathbb N, \, \exists R_n \geq 0, \,  \, \text{s.t,} \,\, \varphi_n (x) \leq R_n.
   $$
   Then
   \begin{align}
   A=& \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{R_n \geq 0}\left\{ x\in E:\varphi_n(x) \leq R_n\right\}\\
   =&  \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{R_n \geq 0} \varphi_n^{-1}(]0,R_n])
   \end{align}
2. $A = \Pi_{n=0}^\infty f^{-1}(\{x\in X: \varphi_n (x) \leq R_n\})$, where $R_n \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$.

Which method  enough to establish that $A$ is measurable with respect to $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
A=\bigcup_{m\ge 1}\left\{x\in X:\sup_{n\ge 1}|f_n(x)|\le m\right\}.
$$